# PHP script stops working after sometime

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made one script in php that run as cron file. what actually  this file does is read large CSV file (maximum 100MB ) ,filter data and save into database.
When I run this file for 5000 records in CSV file it only takes 3500 records and then stop working.

I am using codeigniter and getting followin error "webpage not available"

Can anyone provide me solution for script ?

Thanks !

Comment: I already put on top following code
set_time_limit(0);

Comment: There could be lots of reasons, but probably max_execution_time

Comment: What error message/s do you get when it stops running?

Comment: "webpage not available" this error

Comment: Are you using codeigniter??

Comment: Yes , I am using codeigniter

Comment: @panther : File is too large to post here but its functionality is read file,filter data and save into database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `system/core/Codeigniter.php`, search for `set_time_limit` you got below line of code .You can change here `set_time_limit` in codignator

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);// change it according to your requirment
}
```

As there was no other way to avoid changing the core file,  as well as give the infinite maximum execution time for a CLI request.

Comment: I don't know that why this guys are giving negative rank to this question.
? and how to know that who has given you negative rank  ?

Comment: Have a look at the comments under your question @RonakChauhan. Many have explained their down votes.

Comment: nobody's know but only one thing sure they comment after given downvote. And you have to improve your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Saty :   this solution is working for me I am again testing this on live server.
Can you please tell me how to remove negative ranking from question ?

Comment: Means it working on you local system!! that's great!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79659/discussion-between-saty-and-ronak-chauhan).